# JS, PHP, MySQL Code errors for mathematical operation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I wrote a small script. I have a form in my page. It takes data from MySQL Database. After that, When user select some options from select panels, I need JS will do math summation and write total in a div/input field.
I wrote the page and got errors. I changed a lot of things after searched similar problems on net and here.

I used `parseInt($.. ,10)` , `document.getElementById("testID").innerHTML` , `document.getElementById("testID").value` , `document.getElementById("testID").val()` and etc...

So, I'm asking your help to correct my errors.
Thanks

Here is the Jsfiddle page link;

[jsfiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/yf5Lr43h/)

My Code (this is the latest version that I have) ;

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatesum() {
    var T = 0;
    var d = document;
    var A = d.getElementById("araclar").val();
    var M = d.getElementById("varis").val();
    var K = d.getElementById("kisiler").val();
    var B = d.getElementById("bavullar").val();
    var C = d.getElementById("cocuklar").val();
    var Ck = d.getElementById("cocukKoltuk").val();
    T = parseInt('A' ,10) * parseInt('M' ,10);
    document.getElementById("toplamm").innerHTML = T;       
      }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<form action="subscribe.php" id="subscribe" method="post" name="subscribe">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">

                                                    <div class="row">

                                                         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                                            <label>NAME<input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="NAME" type="text"></label>
                                                        </div>
                                                         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                                            <label>SURNAME<input class="form-control" name="surname" placeholder="SURNAME" type="text"></label>
                                                        </div>
                                                         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                                            <label>TELEPHONE<input class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="TELEPHONE" type="tel"></label>
                                                        </div>
                                                         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                                            <label>EMAIL<input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" type="email"></label>
                                                        </div>
<hr />
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                                           <label>FROM:<select class="form-control" name="kalkis" id="kalkis" onchange="bolegler(this.value);sifirla();">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <?php
$boleg= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM areas WHERE ust LIKE 0"); 
while($bolges = mysql_fetch_array($boleg)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$bolges['id'].'">'.$bolges['isim'].'</option>';
}
    ?>
</select></label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" id="txtHint">
                                                            <!-- This Code will change after #kalkis change by JS  start-->
                                                           <label>TO:<select name="varis" class="form-control">
                                                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                                    </select></label>
                                                    <!-- This Code will change after #kalkis change by JS  end-->
                                                        </div>
                                                         <div id="datetimepicker" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 input-append date">
                                                            <label>REZERVATION DATE


      <input type="text" class="col-xs-8 form-control" name="rezervasyon" style="float:left;"></input>
      <span class="add-on col-xs-2" style="float: left; margin: -39px 0; font-size: 23px;"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </span>

                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                                            <label>CAR:
                                                                <select name="car" id="car" class="form-control" onchange="updatesum();">
                                                                    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <?php
$ara= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars"); 
while($arac = mysql_fetch_array($ara)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$arac['price'].'" class="'.$arac['id'].'">'.$arac['isim'].'</option>';
}
    ?>

    </select>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                                            <label>PERSON QTY
                                                                <select name="persons" id="persons" class="form-control" onchange="updatesum();">
                                                                <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <?php
$kis= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM person"); 
while($person = mysql_fetch_array($kis)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$person['price'].'" class="'.$person['qty'].'">'.$person['qty'].'</option>';
}
    ?>
    </select>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                                            <label>bag QTY
                                                               <select name="bags" id="bags" class="form-control" onchange="updatesum();">
                                                                <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <?php
$bav= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bag"); 
while($bag = mysql_fetch_array($bav)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$bag['price'].'" class="'.$bag['qty'].'">'.$bag['qty'].'</option>';
}
    ?>
    </select>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                                            <label>KID QTY
                                                                <select name="cocuklar" id="cocuklar" class="form-control" onchange="updatesum();cocukla();">
                                                                <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <?php
$coc= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kidqty"); 
while($kid = mysql_fetch_array($coc)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$kid['price'].'" class="'.$kid['qty'].'">'.$kid['qty'].'</option>';
}
    ?>
    </select>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" id="koltukalani">
                                                            <label>KID CHAIR 
                                                                <select name='kidchair' id='kidchair' class='form-control' onchange='updatesum();'> 
                                                                    <option value='0'>Please Select</option> 
                                                                    <option value='0'>Do no Want</option> 
                                                                    <option value='<?php echo $genel['kidchair']; ?>'>Need a Kid Chair</option> 
                                                                </select> 
                                                            </label> 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                                                    <button class="form-control submit-button" id="submit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                                                    <br />
                                                    TOTAL AMOUNT:
                                                    <div id="toplamm" class="toplamm">0</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            </form>
```

And the Other Codes:

function sifirla:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sifirla() {
    document.getElementById("toplamm").innerHTML = "0";
}
      </script>
```

function cocukla:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
function cocukla() {
var cocuk = parseInt(document.getElementById("cocuklar").value);
    if (cocuk < "1") {
    document.getElementById("kidchair").innerHTML = " ";
    }
else {
    document.getElementById("kidchair").innerHTML = "<label>KID CHAIR <select name='kidchair' id='kidchair' class='form-control' onchange='updatesum();'> <option value='0'>Please Select</option> <option value='0'>Do not Want</option> <option value='<?php echo $genel['kidchair']; ?>'>Need a Kid Chair</option> </select> </label>"; }
}

      </script>
```

Comment: try`parseInt(A ,10) * parseInt(M ,10);`

Comment: Thanks Azzi, but it didn't help.
I chaged code like : 
`T = parseInt(A ,10) * parseInt(M ,10) + K + B + C + Ck;`
vars are different but I have correct ids in places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line  `T = parseInt('A' ,10) * parseInt('M' ,10);` you are using trying to get the ASCII code of char A and char M. Whereas you should be parsing variables A and M to integer.

You will need to modify your function as below to get the correct numbers-

```
T = parseInt(A ,10) * parseInt(M ,10);
```

Updated as per comment -

Use `value` instead of `val()` for getting the values form html id tags.

```
T = parseInt(A ,10) * parseInt(M ,10) + parseInt(K ,10) + parseInt(B ,10) + parseInt(C ,10) + parseInt(Ck ,10);
```

Comment: Thanks Chandan, but it didn't help. I chaged code like : T = parseInt(A ,10) * parseInt(M ,10) + K + B + C + Ck; vars are different but I have correct ids in places.

Comment: What is your K, B, C and Ck variables, are they int. Because if you want to add them then they need to be parsed to int as well.

Comment: there is no method as `val()` on `d.getElementById("araclar").val()` change all references of `val()` to `value`.

Comment: `val()` is used when you work with jQuery and `value` when directly with DOM such as `document.getElementById(' ').value`.

Comment: this is worked for me. I used value before but I use it with 

`T = parseInt(A ,10) * parseInt(M ,10) + parseInt(K ,10) + parseInt(B ,10) + parseInt(C ,10) + parseInt(Ck ,10);`
So I think this had to be used in my case as solution. Thanks for your help. Please write it as answer So I can submit it as answer.
Thanks again...

Comment: Thanks ! Updated the answer.

Comment: Chandan, How can I use another variable for the math. Like class or any data attribute like data-value="$a" or class="$a". Because i need the values for the registration process.
Thanks

Comment: what is the html code from where you want to extract the values ??

Comment: at the same sample;
here is the jsfiddle [page link](http://jsfiddle.net/o8uk8w2r/1/)